# Php multi array loop to return a number and store in a variable

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$values = array(
array("temperature",5,6,7,8,9,10),
array("-20",0.05,0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11),
array("-19",0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.11,0.12),
array("-18",0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.13),
array("-17",0.07,0.08,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.14),
array("-16",0.07,0.09,0.1,0.12,0.13,0.15),
array("-15",0.08,0.1,0.11,0.13,0.14,0.16)
);
```

And I have two variables that I get from a user input form

```
  $temperature= $_POST['temperature'];
  $humidity= $_POST['humidity'];
```

I need help with going through the array to retrieve the value that corresponds to the two variables and store it in another variable for the purpose of doing a simple calculation.

For example: If the $temperature = -20, and $humidity = 5
the value I would need is

```
$values[1][$humidity-4] (which is basically 1,1)
```

Which would be 0.05.

Here is what I tried earlier using a CSV but it created a timeout on the webpage.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: watercalc
Plugin URI:
Description: Calculates water generation
Version: 1.0
Author: Chefattack
 Author URI:
 */

  //WordPress Hooks
 add_shortcode('wcalc', 'run_bc');
 function run_bc()
 {
 // If the submit button has been pressed
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 // Check number values
 if(is_numeric($_POST['temperature']) && 
 is_numeric($_POST['humidity']))
 {
// Calculate total


function getValueFromCSV($csv_name) {
  $humidity= $_POST['humidity'];
  $temperature= $_POST['temperature'];
  $file = fopen($csv_name, "r");
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $arr = fgetcsv($file);
    if ($arr[0] == $temperature) {
      $coefficient= $arr[$humidity - 4];
      if($_POST['models'] == 'pod')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.03 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '36K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.1 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '55K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.15 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '110K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.25 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '180K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 0.5 *60 * 24 *365);
      }
      if($_POST['models'] == '365K')
      {
        $total = round($coefficient * 0.0287801747544059 * 1 *60 * 24 *365);
      }

      // Print total to the browser
      echo "<h4> Water Generation at $humidity% Relative Humidity and $temperature C<br>Per Year: ~ {$total} ltrs.</h4>";
    }
  }
  fclose($file);
}
// Function Calling
getValueFromCSV('akvo-values.csv');

} else {

// Print error message to the browser
 echo 'Numeric values are required';

  }
 }

 ?>

 <form method='post' action='<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'>
 <label>Temperature (Celcius)</label><br>
 <select name="temperature" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; display: block">
    <?php for ($i = -20; $i <= 60; $i++) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </select><br>
<label>Relative Humidity (%)</label><br>
<select name="humidity" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; display: block">
    <?php for ($i = 5; $i <= 100; $i++) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </select><br>
<label>Choose Akvo Model</label><br>
<select name="models" class="form-control" style="width: 150px; display: block">
  <option value="pod">Akvo Pod</option>
    <option value="36K">Akvo 36K</option>
    <option value="55K">Akvo 55K</option>
    <option value="110K">Akvo 110K</option>
    <option value="180K">180K</option>
    <option value="365K">365K</option>
</select><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-primary" />

 </form>

 <?php
  }
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried please?

Comment: Do the queried values for temperature and humidity always match the ones in the array, or do you need interpolation?

Comment: the queried values will always match as they are being selected from a dropdown with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be calculating the index you need from the original array

```
<?php

$values = array(
    array("temperature",5,6,7,8,9,10),
    array("-20",0.05,0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11),
    array("-19",0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.11,0.12),
    array("-18",0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.13),
    array("-17",0.07,0.08,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.14),
    array("-16",0.07,0.09,0.1,0.12,0.13,0.15),
    array("-15",0.08,0.1,0.11,0.13,0.14,0.16)
);

function getValue($values, $temperature, $humidity) {
    $temperatureIndex = (int)(21 + $temperature);
    $humidityIndex = (int)($humidity - 4);

    return $values[$temperatureIndex][$humidityIndex];
}

echo getValue($values, -20, 5) . PHP_EOL;
echo getValue($values, -16, 9) . PHP_EOL;
```

and here is the output:

```
0.05
0.13
```

For another solution, you can build a 2-dimension lookup table with first index of temperature and second index of humidity.

Here is my example code:

```
<?php

$values = array(
    array("temperature",5,6,7,8,9,10),
    array("-20",0.05,0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11),
    array("-19",0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.11,0.12),
    array("-18",0.06,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.13),
    array("-17",0.07,0.08,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.14),
    array("-16",0.07,0.09,0.1,0.12,0.13,0.15),
    array("-15",0.08,0.1,0.11,0.13,0.14,0.16)
);

// get first row of humidity value
$humidityValue = array_shift($values);
array_shift($humidityValue); // drop the element 'temperature'

// build lookup
$lookup = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    // get temperature from the first element of row
    $temperature = array_shift($value);

    // bind himidityValue and value as associative array
    $humidityOfTemperature = array_combine($humidityValue, $value);

    // insert to look up
    $lookup[$temperature] = $humidityOfTemperature;
}

function getValue($lookup, $temperature, $humidity) {
    // if value of pair (temperature, humidity) is not defined, throw exception
    if (!isset($lookup[$temperature]) || !isset($lookup[$temperature][$humidity])) {
        throw new \Exception("undefined value. temperature => $temperature, humidity => $humidity");
    }

    return $lookup[$temperature][$humidity];
}

$temperature = -20;
$humidity = 5;
echo getValue($lookup, $temperature, $humidity) . PHP_EOL;

$temperature = -15;
$humidity = 10;
echo getValue($lookup, $temperature, $humidity) . PHP_EOL;
```

this is the lookup array:

```
Array
(
    [-20] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.05
            [6] => 0.06
            [7] => 0.08
            [8] => 0.09
            [9] => 0.1
            [10] => 0.11
        )

    [-19] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.06
            [6] => 0.07
            [7] => 0.08
            [8] => 0.09
            [9] => 0.11
            [10] => 0.12
        )

    [-18] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.06
            [6] => 0.08
            [7] => 0.09
            [8] => 0.1
            [9] => 0.11
            [10] => 0.13
       )

    [-17] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.07
            [6] => 0.08
            [7] => 0.1
            [8] => 0.11
            [9] => 0.12
            [10] => 0.14
        )

    [-16] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.07
            [6] => 0.09
            [7] => 0.1
            [8] => 0.12
            [9] => 0.13
            [10] => 0.15
        )

    [-15] => Array
        (
            [5] => 0.08
            [6] => 0.1
            [7] => 0.11
            [8] => 0.13
            [9] => 0.14
            [10] => 0.16
        )

)
```

and here is the output:

```
0.05
0.16
```

Comment: what I had tried earlier using a csv was creating a timeout on the webpage:

Comment: @AdhirajMukherji Maybe you should put `($arr = fgetcsv($file)) !== False` in while() intead. I'm not familiar with working on csv with php.